# What is the least computationally expensive way of making 2 divs mirror their content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my `JavaScript` code. I have the following snippet of code, in which two different divs, `someElement` and `someOtherElement`, are holding the same number at any given time (i.e., the inner text of one mirrors the other. The text represents a score in a game, displayed on two different parts of the web page).

```
var x = $('#someElement');
x.text(x.text()+10);
var y = $('#someOtherElement');
y.text(y.text()+10);
```

I'm thinking I can cut down on 2 operations and some memory by instead doing

```
var x = $('#someElement');
x.text(x.text()+10);
$('#someOtherElement').text(x);
```

But is there an even better way? If possible, I want more elegance and efficiency at the same time.

Comment: You're not Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 1):

Assign them a common class, e.g. "score":

```
var x = $('.score');
x.text(x.text()+10);
```

If that isn't a possibility, use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
var x = $('#someElement, #someOtherElement');
x.text(x.text()+10);
```